# Mockito is not mocking my context

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have the following setup

```
public class Blo{
   private Context mContext;

   public Blo(Context context){
      mContext=context;
   }

   public void updateIfNecessary(Cat cat){
      if(cat.isUpdateNecessary()){
          mContext.getContentResolver().update(cat.getUri(), cat.toContentValues(),null,null);
      }
   }
}
```

Now I am trying to create a Mockito spy to see if the update is executed.

```
public class BloTest{
   @Test
   public void testCatNotUpdatesIfUnnecessary(){
      Context context = Mockito.spy(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext());
      Blo blo = new Blo(context);
      Cat cat = createCat();
      cat.setUpdateNecessary(false);
      final int expected = 1;
      Mockito.doReturn(1).when(context).getContentResolver();
      assertEquals(1, blo.updateIfNecessary(cat));
   }
}
```

Now of course I have no idea if I am doing the test correctly. But even before we get to the test, I am getting error when I try to run the test:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Mockito cannot mock this class: class android.app.ContextImpl.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
```

How can I set up my test case correctly so as to be able to test both when the update is made and when the update is not made? This is my first time using Mockito.

Answer (score 2):

You production code violates the *Law of demeter* (aka *Don't talk to strangers!*) 
You access an *indirect dependency* here:

```
mContext.getContentResolver().update()
```

Because of this you have to do more effort configuring your test case:

```
   @Rule 
   public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule(); 
   @Mock
   Context context;
   @Mock
   ContentResolver contentResolver;

   @Test
   public void testCatNotUpdatesIfUnnecessary(){
      doReturn(contentResolver).when(context).getContentResolver()
      Blo blo = new Blo(context);
      Cat cat = createCat();
      cat.setUpdateNecessary(false);

      blo.updateIfNecessary(cat);

      verify(contentResolver)
            .update(cat.getUri(), cat.toContentValues(),null,null);
   }
```

However,
The better solution of cause is to refactor the production code and inject the instance of  `ContentResolver` directly instead of `Context`...

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I see that in your example you never called `blo.updateIfNecessary(cat)`. That's the method I need to test. I know contentResolver#udpate(...) works, but that is not what I want to test. I want to test whether -- inside the method blo#updateIfNecessary(cat) -- udpate is called or not. Does that make sense?

Comment: @salyela it is a fine answer.
However, I don't find satisfactory to double mocks.
It makes tests more verbose and more brittle (and I suppose that `mContext.getContentResolver()` should also be mocked at other places) and it results also to implementation code with too much coupled dependencies. You should rather refactor your code if this requirement is frequent.

Comment: @davidxxx obviously my intro to the answer was not clear enough... updated it.

Comment: @Timothy Truckle It is clearer now. I had already upvoted. I see that it was downvoted  since. I really don't understand  why...

Comment: @davidxxx I already gave up trying to understand downvoting motivations... ;o)